# Cmake variables for systemd are empty

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, pkg-config

I want to start/stop a systemd service from within my C++ project. Therefore I like to use the systemd lib and headers provided. I'm using cmake for makefile generation. I'm trying to get systemd in cmake via

```
pkg_check_modules(SDBUS REQUIRED systemd)
```

which actually works as

`message(STATUS "FOUND" ${SDBUS_FOUND})`  returns 1.

However, all the other necessary vars created by cmake like

```
message(STATUS "LIBS" ${SDBUS_LIBRARIES})
message(STATUS "LIB_DIRS" ${SDBUS_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(STATUS "LDFLAGS" ${SDBUS_LDFLAGS})
message(STATUS "LDFLAGS_OTHER" ${SDBUS_LDFLAGS_OTHER})
message(STATUS "INCLUDE DIRS" ${SDBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "CFLAGS" ${SDBUS_CFLAGS})
message(STATUS "CFLAGS_OTHER" ${SDBUS_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

are empty. Which leads to a linker error when compiling the project. Indeed when calling

```
pkg-config --libs systemd
```

it's empty as well. Anyone has any idea on how to solve that and why all these information is not available for systemd?

Comment: when changing

`pkg_check_modules(SDBUS REQUIRED systemd)`

to

`pkg_check_modules(SYSTEMD REQUIRED systemd)`

and applying it to all the other stuff it works. weired.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
pkg_check_modules(SDBUS REQUIRED libsystemd)
```

Note the extra 'lib' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can see systemd does not provide them

```
%pkg-config systemd --print-variables
binfmtdir
catalogdir
containeruidbasemax
containeruidbasemin
dynamicuidmax
dynamicuidmin
modulesloaddir
pcfiledir
prefix
sysctldir
systemdshutdowndir
systemdsleepdir
systemdsystemconfdir
systemdsystemgeneratordir
systemdsystempresetdir
systemdsystemunitdir
systemdsystemunitpath
systemduserconfdir
systemdusergeneratordir
systemduserpresetdir
systemduserunitdir
systemduserunitpath
systemdutildir
systemgidmax
systemuidmax
sysusersdir
tmpfilesdir
```

So [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) module is of no use here...

you should use [libsystemd-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libsystemd-dev/filelist) instead

then you'll have

```
%pkg-config libsystemd --print-variables
exec_prefix
includedir
libdir
pcfiledir
prefix

%pkg-config libsystemd --libs           
-lsystemd
```

Comment: Your first output uses 'pkg-config systemd' which isn't a library, so it doesn't print includedir etc. Your final output uses libsystemd - which is the library. I think that the OP, if he wants libsystemd should use: `pkg_check_modules(SDBUS REQUIRED libsystemd)`